# How to move a photo/video to an album with Flutter on mobile (iOS and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-gallery

Using Flutter on mobile (iOS and Android), how can I move media to an album?

I tried to combine `gallery_saver` and `photo_manager` on iOS:

1. I read a media `AssetEntity` from `Recents`
2. Saved the `AssetEntity` file under an album with `GallerySaver.saveImage`. At this point `Recents` showed the same media twice, makes sense.
3. Attempted to delete with `PhotoManager.editor.deleteWithIds` the original `AssetEntity` file, and it showed a native popup asking the user if it's ok to delete the media. Bad user experience...

Is there a way to change `AssetEntity` album, without creating a new file?

Comment: Updated my answer providing example change that needs to be done.

Comment: Would be great marking my answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: @om-ha I appreciate the effort, but it's not the full solution I'm looking for, since it doesn't address Android.

Comment: I see. I presumed this was an iOS-specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

## April 2020 Update

Thankfully, the author of the library recently updated it to include album removal feature discussed in this answer. You can see their [pull request](https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_photo_manager/pull/241). Or refer to the method invocation `removeAssetsInAlbum` in the [README](https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_photo_manager#only-for-ios)

## Problem

`photo_manager` library is using [PHAssetChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest?language=objc)'s method [deleteAssets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624062-deleteassets?language=objc). You can see this [here](https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_photo_manager/blob/2d4ae4909c0e19c33c9b2809e8b92f822ef32494/ios/Classes/core/PMManager.m#L674). This will delete the actual file rather than just remove it from album (more on this in Explanation section)

## Solution

The solution is to use [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest?language=objc)'s methods. Depends on your use case:

#### Moving assets from album to another

- [moveAssets(at:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619443-moveassets?language=objc)

#### Removing assets from an album

- [removeAssets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619452-removeassets?language=objc)
- [removeAssets(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619444-removeassets?language=objc)

#### Adding assets to an album

- [addAssets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619446-addassets?language=objc)

## Explanation

There's a difference between deleting assets and removing assets. Deleting an asset's file is done via [PHAssetChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest?language=objc) which deletes the asset file permanently and its references from albums. But removing an asset is done via [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest?language=objc) which removes the asset's reference (not file) from album/s without deleting the file itself. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281743/10830091).

## What to do? How can this solution be applied?

**This section is now obsolete but kept for other use-cases when `photo_manager` cannot be used, please refer to the top of this answer if you want to use `photo_manager`**

<strike>You have the following options to pick one from that would solve your problem:</strike>

- Look for the album methods I explained above in the library `photo_manager`, maybe it's there? **EDIT1** I just looked for [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest?language=objc)'s methods. [Currently](https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_photo_manager/blob/2d4ae4909c0e19c33c9b2809e8b92f822ef32494/ios/Classes/core/PMManager.m#L674) not supported/used.
- Add an issue to the library and ask the author to make said changes
- Add them to the library yourself via PR or your own cloned version of the
  library
- Use a platform channel of your own and handle it yourself.

#### Example Change:

Currently `photo_manager` [uses](https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_photo_manager/blob/2d4ae4909c0e19c33c9b2809e8b92f822ef32494/ios/Classes/core/PMManager.m#L674) `PHAssetChangeRequest`'s method [deleteAssets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624062-deleteassets?language=objc):

```c
[PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:result];
```

This should change to using `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest`'s method [removeAssets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619452-removeassets?language=objc):

```c
[PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest removeAssets:result];
```

Comment: Yes, this is a problem. I am the author of photo_manager. I will add new APIs in the future to support iOS's scheme of removing assets from albums instead of deleting assets.

Comment: Much appreciated @K.Cai!

Comment: HI, photo_manager support the function of removing only asset from album instead of deleting asset in 0.5.1-dev.3. The pub release version will be posted few days. @om-ha